# How to make a custom tab in my account section in opencart 3?

Tags: opencart-module, opencart-3

Can anyone tell me that how can i make a custom tab in **Customer Account** section.

I have try using replace default **myaccount.twig** file. I don't know this is right way or not.

Thanks in advance....!

```
{{ header }}
<div id="account-account" class="container">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    {% for breadcrumb in breadcrumbs %}
    <li><a href="{{ breadcrumb.href }}">{{ breadcrumb.text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% if success %}
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> {{ success }}</div>
  {% endif %}
  <div class="row">{{ column_left }}
    {% if column_left and column_right %}
    {% set class = 'col-sm-6' %}
    {% elseif column_left or column_right %}
    {% set class = 'col-sm-9' %}
    {% else %}
    {% set class = 'col-sm-12' %}
    {% endif %}
    <div id="content" class="{{ class }}">{{ content_top }}
      <h2>{{ text_my_account }}</h2>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><a href="{{ edit }}">{{ text_edit }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ password }}">{{ text_password }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ address }}">{{ text_address }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ wishlist }}">{{ text_wishlist }}</a></li>
      </ul>
      {% if credit_cards %}
      <h2>{{ text_credit_card }}</h2>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        {% for credit_card in credit_cards %}
        <li><a href="{{ credit_card.href }}">{{ credit_card.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      {% endif %}
      <h2>{{ text_my_orders }}</h2>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><a href="{{ order }}">{{ text_order }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ download }}">{{ text_download }}</a></li>
        {% if reward %}
        <li><a href="{{ reward }}">{{ text_reward }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        <li><a href="{{ return }}">{{ text_return }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ transaction }}">{{ text_transaction }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ recurring }}">{{ text_recurring }}</a></li>
      </ul>
      <h2>{{ text_my_affiliate }}</h2>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        {% if not tracking %}
        <li><a href="{{ affiliate }}">{{ text_affiliate_add }}</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ affiliate }}">{{ text_affiliate_edit }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ tracking }}">{{ text_tracking }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
      <h2>{{ text_my_newsletter }}</h2>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><a href="{{ newsletter }}">{{ text_newsletter }}</a></li>
      </ul>
      <h2>{{ text_my_title }}</h2>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><a href="{{ myurl }}">{{ text_url }}</a></li>
      </ul>
      {{ content_bottom }}</div>
    {{ column_right }}</div>
</div>
{{ footer }}
```

Above code is default account.twig file in which i have add just my code

```
 <h2>{{ text_my_title }}</h2>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="{{ myurl }}">{{ text_url }}</a></li>
          </ul>
```

So this is Right way or not? This code is works but when i am uninstll this module it will remove default account.twig file.

Please guide me in this sinario. Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Not only twig files you must edit. You should edit also corresponding controller, language, maybe model files to define data what you wish to show in your twig file. And after you make some changes, do not forget clear cache in OC admin dashboard and refresh modifications.

Comment: Actully i am make custom extension for opencart. So can you please provide me some more info about it..! Thanks

Comment: If i am made changes according to your suggestion i am got this error while installation. Please check this screen shot : https://www.screencast.com/t/mlDwLcMoBZeI

Comment: if you wish some help you should place your code here. If files not writing somewhere you should check permissions and set it properly. for directories 755 for files 644. Seems you installing ocmod.. how this file is configured?

Comment: @K.B. I have update code please check and give me solution. Thanks

Comment: for implementing some piece of the code to twig or php files you should use vqmod or ocmod. You never need edit core files. In this case  Installation or uninstallation of the modules does not remove your core files.